# Tabulator 4.6: "Load Table Data From Local File" fails to post JSON file to Tabulator table

Tags: tabulator

Using Tabulator 4.6 Example "Load Table Data From Local File".  However selection
"data.json" file from by desktop, nothing happens.  Unfortunately, the Tabulator 4.6
example for this seem to not work (intermittent).  My HTML script is listed below.  I
am using MS Visual Studio Code as my IDE.  This is a copy of the Tabulator 4.6 "Load
Table Data From Local File".  I have include all the Links, etc in the 
section.

```
Again, my issue is why the selected JSON file does not load into the Tabulator table?
```

You can see this Tabulator example using this link  http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6#file-load

This is my first time and question using stack overflow.  Sorry for a misunderstanding. I tried loading my html file/script without success.  Will have to practice or find on Youtube.com

---

I think I figured loading code into StackOverflow. The code below is all there and correct.  This code you will find in Tabular website Examples for "Load Table Data from Local File".  Appreciate any help you could share, reference, etc.   I am using MS Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

PS:  Oli, your Tabulator website Example does not display the data upon a download of a .JSON file!   Is is the example website script or my network issue.  Tried your website example using two browsers (C, F) and two OS's (Linux, Win10).

Mahalo,
Pajaro

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button id="file-load-trigger">Open File</button>
    </div>
    <div id="example-table"></div>

    <h2>tabulator-upload upload table Data from local JSON file</h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Build Tabulator
      var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height: "311px",
        layout: "fitColumns",
        autoColumns: true,
        placeholder: "No Data Set",
      });

      //trigger AJAX load on "Load Data via AJAX" button click
      document
        .getElementById("file-load-trigger")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          table.setDataFromLocalFile();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, do share code snippet and any error message you are getting.

Comment: I'm not seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry, could not get code to load by following code directions (sucks).

Comment: Well this is not really as SO question it is an issue to be filed here: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Tabulator 4.7.1, see the issue https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2886. It seems to be a problem with autoColumns.
If you try this simple json:

```
[ {"name":"Billy Bob", "age":"12"}, {"name":"Mary May", "age":"24"}, {"name":"Christine Lobowski", "age":"15"} ]
```

with this table initialization:

```
//autoColumns:true,
columns:[ //Define Table Columns
    {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", sorter:"number", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
],
```

It seems to work

Comment: Aloha Stavn,  Thanks for the answer.  I wasn't sure how to contact Developer to remedy the issue.  But I see Mr. Olifolkerd has gotten the issue.  Will test S/T next week.  Mahalo (thanks in Hawaiian)